# dredd is expecting example of parameter in swagger json

Tags: json, swagger, dredd

I made my first swagger api spec and dredd gave error:

`error: Compilation error in file '../../docs/swagger.json': 
Required URI parameter 'id_person' has no example or default value. (person > /person/{id_person} > Updates a already existing person ID with form data)`

So I gave a default value to the parameter and now getting warning from dredd:

`Required URI parameter 'id_person' has a default value.
Default value for a required parameter doesn't make sense from API description perspective. Use example value instead.`

I want to give example IDs in the spec, but I cannot find how to in the Swagger Specification.

My snip of my swagger:

```
"post": {
                "tags": ["person"],
                "summary": "Updates a already existing person ID with form data",
                "operationId": "createNewPerson",
                "consumes": ["application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],
                "produces": ["application/json", "application/xml"],
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "id_person",
                        "in": "path",
                        "description": "ID of person to update",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "integer",
                        "format": "int64",
                        "default": 1
                    },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to
https://dredd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to-guides/#example-values-for-request-parameters
Dredd supports the `x-example` extension property to specify the parameter examples:

```
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "id_person",
                        "in": "path",
                        "description": "ID of person to update",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "integer",
                        "format": "int64",
                        "x-example": 1
                    },
```